How do I enable CONFIG_SPIRAM_SUPPORT for ESP32 S3 on Arduino?
I'm trying to use PSRAM with the TFT_eSPI library, but it fails because CONFIG_SPIRAM_SUPPORT isn't defined.
In Arduino -> Tools -> PSRAM I selected OPI PSRAM as the board manufacturer (the board is a Lilygo T-HMI with ESP32 S3) recommends, but that seems to not do anything in this respect.
How can I fix this?

One example from the library built fine. But then, I'm not using your code, your library version, your esp32 core version, and probably have not configured the board in exactly the way you have.

Which example did you check?

The  TFT_eSPI library should be configured correctly to use PSRAM.

@liaifat85 It is setup to use PSRAM if CONFIG_SPIRAM_SUPPORT is defined, which it isn't in my setup for some reason. If I comment out the check for this in TFT_eSPI and thus force it to use PSRAM, then it works flawlessly and uses PSRAM without issues. But I'd like to have PSRAM working the "proper" way without hacking around and manually modifying the library, which breaks when I update the library at any time. So I'm looking for a way to enable the CONFIG_SPIRAM_SUPPORT preprocessor define.
